# How to create new dataframes from data frame which has Multi level columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I’ve this dataframe and want to create various other dataframes which consist of the Column State and other columns whose subtraction is to be done along with the subtraction result and the level 0 column name.
Dataframe:

```
|State| Sheet1    | Sheet2  | Sheet3|
|     |count|c |d |count| c | d     |
|:————|:———:|—-|—:|:——-:|:—:|:————-:|
|x    | 100 |23|34|50   |4  | 56    |
|:————|:———:|—-|—:|:——-:|:—:|:————-:|
|y    | 300 |13|34|60   |41 | 32    |
|:————|:———:|—-|—:|:——-:|:—:|:————-:|
```

Desired dataframes are:

```
|State|Sheet1|Sheet2|Difference|
|     |count |count |          |
|:————|:——-—:|———-—:|:—————-—-:|
|x    | 100  |50    | 50       |
|:————|:——-—:|———-—:|:—————-—-:|
|y    | 300  |60    |240       |
|:————|:——-—:|————-:|:——————-—:|
```

And so on.

Comment: Will you please share a sample of your dataframe as code? It looks pretty hard to reproduce.

Comment: This data has been created by merging several sheets and basically the columns are named in levels I.e level 0 has State, Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3 then level 1 has count,C,D. @richardec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to first select the columns that you want we can use `get_level_values` this way:

```
>> df = df.iloc[:, (df.columns.get_level_values(0) == "State") | (df.columns.get_level_values(1) == "count")]
>> df
  State Sheet1 Sheet2
    NaN  count  count
0     x    100     50
1     y    300     60
```

We are selecting all the columns where level 0 is equal to `"State"` or where level 1 is equal to `"count"`. Now, you want to create a `("Difference", None)` column (no level 1). We can do this by selecting the columns and using the proper format to specify the column that we are creating:

```
>> df[("Difference", None)] = df[("Sheet1", "count")] - df[("Sheet2", "count")]
>> df
  State Sheet1 Sheet2 Difference
    NaN  count  count        NaN
0     x    100     50         50
1     y    300     60        240
```